# Why won't Simple HTML DOM Parser go through some sites?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

**Edit: When I add error_reporting(-1); I get this error message:**

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /data/22/2/145/126/2960289/user/3282682/htdocs/add.php on line 106

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /data/22/2/145/126/2960289/user/3282682/htdocs/add.php on line 108
```

I'm trying to use Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to search through sites. It worked well on localhost but when I uploaded it to my host (Network Solutions), some urls didn't give any results anymore. It occurred when I switched from file_get_html to str_get_html. I had to do it because of the host. Do you have any idea what's wrong? I'm sorry about how the script looks but I'm kind of a newbie... Maybe you have some tips on how to compress it a bit? The script looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
include("connect.php");

if (isset($_POST['done'])) {

    function getimg($url) {         
        $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif, image/x-bitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg';              
        $headers[] = 'Connection: Keep-Alive';         
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';         
        $user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)';         
        $process = curl_init($url);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
        curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);         
        $return = curl_exec($process);         
        curl_close($process);         
        return $return;     
    } 

    $imgurl = $_POST['finalimg'];
    $random = substr(number_format(time() * rand(),0,'',''),0,30);
    $imagename= basename($random.".jpg");
    if(file_exists('./upload/'.$imagename)){continue;} 
    $image = getimg($imgurl); 
    file_put_contents('upload/'.$imagename,$image);

    $finalurl = $_POST['finalurl'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $titlen = $_POST['title'];
    $pricen = $_POST['price'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO samples(description, name, productUrl, imageUrl, price)
        VALUES('$description', '$titlen', '$finalurl', '$imagename', '$pricen')";
    mysql_query($sql);

        // Skickar vidare
        header("Location: collection.php?id={$_SESSION['sess_id']}");
        exit;

}

include("head.php");
?>

<div class="content add-content">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Add your picture</span></h1>
    </div>

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require('DOM/simple_html_dom.php');
    require('DOM/example/url_to_absolute.php');

    $url = $_POST['url'];

    $curl = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);  
    $str = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  

    $html = str_get_html($str);

    foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {

        $linktoimg = url_to_absolute($url, $element->src);

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $linktoimg);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


        $contents = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);


        $new_image = ImageCreateFromString($contents);
        imagejpeg($new_image, "temp.jpg",100);


    $size = getimagesize("temp.jpg");


        // width and height


        $width = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];

        echo $linktoimg . " Height: " . $height . " Width: " . $width . "<br />";

        if ($height >= 200) {

        $title1 = $html->find(".product_title");
        $title11 = $title1[0]->plaintext;
        $title2 = $html->find(".product-title");
        $title22 = $title2[0]->plaintext;
        $title3 = $html->find(".product_name");
        $title33 = $title3[0]->plaintext;
        $title4 = $html->find(".product_name");
        $title44 = $title4[0]->plaintext;
        $title5 = $html->find("h1");
        $title55 = $title5[0]->plaintext;

        if ($title55 != "") {
            $title = $title55;
        }

        if ($title44 != "") {
            $title = $title44;
        }

        if ($title33 != "") {
            $title = $title33;
        }

        if ($title22 != "") {
            $title = $title22;
        }

        if ($title11 != "") {
            $title = $title11;
        }

        $desc1 = $html->find("p .product_description");
        $desc11 = $desc1[0]->plaintext;
        $desc2 = $html->find("p .product-description");
        $desc22 = $desc2[0]->plaintext;
        $desc3 = $html->find("p .description");
        $desc33 = $desc3[0]->plaintext;
        $desc4 = $html->find(".product-description");
        $desc44 = $desc4[0]->plaintext;
        $desc5 = $html->find(".product_description");
        $desc55 = $desc5[0]->plaintext;
        $desc6 = $html->find(".description");
        $desc66 = $desc6[0]->plaintext;

        if ($desc66 != "") {
            $desc = $desc66;
        }

        if ($desc55 != "") {
            $desc = $desc55;
        }

        if ($desc44 != "") {
            $desc = $desc44;
        }

        if ($desc33 != "") {
            $desc = $desc33;
        }

        if ($desc22 != "") {
            $desc = $desc22;
        }

        if ($desc11 != "") {
            $desc = $desc11;
        }

        $price1 = $html->find(".product_price");
        $price11 = $price1[0]->plaintext;
        $price2 = $html->find(".product-price");
        $price22 = $price2[0]->plaintext;
        $price3 = $html->find(".price");
        $price33 = $price3[0]->plaintext;
        $price4 = $html->find("#product_price");
        $price44 = $price4[0]->plaintext;
        $price5 = $html->find("#product-price");
        $price55 = $price5[0]->plaintext;
        $price6 = $html->find("#price");
        $price66 = $price6[0]->plaintext;
        $price7 = $html->find(".product_price_details");
        $price77 = $price7[0]->plaintext;
        $price8 = $html->find(".price-red");
        $price88 = $price8[0]->plaintext;

        if ($price88 != "") {
            $price = $price88;
        }

        if ($price77 != "") {
            $price = $price77;
        }

        if ($price66 != "") {
            $price = $price66;
        }

        if ($price55 != "") {
            $price = $price55;
        }

        if ($price44 != "") {
            $price = $price44;
        }

        if ($price33 != "") {
            $price = $price33;
        }

        if ($price22 != "") {
            $price = $price22;
        }

        if ($price11 != "") {
            $price = $price11;
        }

            ?>

            <form action="add.php" method="post">
                <div class="add-wrapper">
                    <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: -40px;">Is this a good picture?</div>
                    <div class="add-window">
                        <img src="timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $linktoimg; ?>&zc=3&h=432&w=500" style="border: 1px solid #000;" />
                    </div>

                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="finalurl" value="<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="finalimg" value="<?php echo $linktoimg; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="description" value="<?php echo $desc; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>">
                <input type="submit" value="" class="submit" name="done" style="margin-top: 40px;">
            </form>

            <?php
            echo $title . "<br /><br />";
            echo $desc . "<br /><br />";
            echo $price;
        break;

        }

    }

    } else {

    ?>

    <form action="add.php" method="post">

    <div class="add-url">
        <input type="text" name="url" class="biginput" placeholder="Paste the link...">
        <input type="submit" class="bigsubmit" value="" name="submit">
    </div>

    </form>

    <?php

    }

    ?>

</div>

<?php
include("feet.php");
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You can enable error reporting by  ``error_reporting(-1);`` to your script.

Comment: Nothing happens.. Although, when I user error_reporting on the pages that I'm able to scrape, I get the error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /data/22/2/145/126/2960289/user/3282682/htdocs/add.php on line 104

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /data/22/2/145/126/2960289/user/3282682/htdocs/add.php on line 106"

Comment: @KarlSandgren: That error message is crucial, not an afterthought.  Please go put it back into your question and give specific details about how you make that occur.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not accept this as an answer, because it isn't**.

You can shorten

```php
$price1 = $html->find(".product_price");
$price11 = $price1[0]->plaintext;
$price2 = $html->find();
$price22 = $price2[0]->plaintext;
$price3 = $html->find();
$price33 = $price3[0]->plaintext;
$price4 = $html->find();
$price44 = $price4[0]->plaintext;
$price5 = $html->find();
$price55 = $price5[0]->plaintext;
$price6 = $html->find();
$price66 = $price6[0]->plaintext;
$price7 = $html->find();
$price77 = $price7[0]->plaintext;
$price8 = $html->find();
$price88 = $price8[0]->plaintext;

if ($price88 != "") {
    $price = $price88;
}

if ($price77 != "") {
    $price = $price77;
}

if ($price66 != "") {
    $price = $price66;
}

if ($price55 != "") {
    $price = $price55;
}

if ($price44 != "") {
    $price = $price44;
}

if ($price33 != "") {
    $price = $price33;
}

if ($price22 != "") {
    $price = $price22;
}

if ($price11 != "") {
    $price = $price11;
}
```

To the following:

```php
$selectors = array(
    ".product_price",
    ".product-price",
    ".price",
    "#product_price",
    "#product-price",
    "#price",
    ".product_price_details",
    ".price-red"
);

foreach ($selectors as $selector) {
    $selectorPrice = $html->find($selector, 0)->plaintext;
    if (!empty($selectorPrice)) {
        $price = $selectorPrice;
        break;
    }
}
```

A good thing to remember while coding is that if your code looks the same for several lines, it's most likely able to shorten it (and save performance/improve understanding).

Answer (score 0):

Some hosting providers have a security tab where you can set up allowed IPs for outgoing connections. This is mainly for security reasons, and it's the same reason why some users cannot upgrade or check upgrades for Joomla, Joomla tries to connect to an external site to check updates but it is blocked by the server.

This is an example of the allowed IPs outgoing connections tab on Hepsia control panel:

[image: Example of outgoing allowed IPs fro Hepsia]

If you have something like this, you need to add trusted urls manually, after you add them, the server should let you reach them

Comment: I guess that could work. The problem is that my script is going to scrape a LOT of pages and therefore I need to make it work on sites I don't know exist yet. Thanks so much anyway!

Comment: Let me know if you find some better solution to this